# A Number Theoretic Argument. Proof or counter-example!

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Can we find two consecutive integers $n$ and $n+1$ that are divisible by the same prime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint** If $a\mid b$ and $a\mid c,$ then $a\mid(c-b)$.

Answer (score 2):

You can't because $\gcd(n,n+1)=1$, because...